# Spring Cloud GCP is not receiving messages from subscription

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I have a trained Chatbot in DialogFlow. I enabled logging for the chatbot and it logs to Google StackDriver. From Google StackDriver, using a log router, I have routed the logs to a Google Cloud Pub-Sub topic. Then, with a subscription, I have subscribed to this topic. The Pub-Sub works fine. I have setup Google Cloud SDK in my Ubuntu PC. Using gcloud commands, I can pull messages from the Pub-Sub subscription and it works.

Now, I implemented a Spring Boot application to subscribe to Pub-Sub. I followed [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-integration/#0) tutorial. Find the code below. The application does not receive messages from Pub-Sub. It is supposed to log the received message. Can anyone tell me what I may be missing here? How can I test if this actually works? Please comment if further information is needed.

> ChatboardApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ChatboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChatboardApplication.class, args);
    }

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(ChatboardApplication.class);

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("pubsubInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
                new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, "agent-genie-sub");
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);

        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel")
    public void messageReceiver(String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("Message arrived! Payload: " + payload);
    }

}
```

> ChatboardProducerApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ChatboardProducerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChatboardProducerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {

        void sendToPubsub(String text);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubsubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubsubTemplate, "agent-genie-logs");
    }

    @Autowired
    private PubsubOutboundGateway messagingGateway;

    @PostMapping("/postMessage")
    public RedirectView postMessage(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
        this.messagingGateway.sendToPubsub(message);
        return new RedirectView("/");
    }

}
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dialog</groupId>
    <artifactId>chatboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chatboard</name>
    <description>PubSub subscriber and Dashboard backend</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> application.properties

```
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=#########
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:#######################
```

> Curl command to test applications

```
curl --data "message=Hello world!" localhost:8080/postMessage
```

> Edit - Error after several minutes

After some time from the applications started and running curl command, I get the following error.

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69) ~[gax-1.54.0.jar:1.54.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[gax-grpc-1.54.0.jar:1.54.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[gax-grpc-1.54.0.jar:1.54.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) [gax-grpc-1.54.0.jar:1.54.0]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) [api-common-1.8.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1039) [guava-28.2-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) [guava-28.2-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1165) [guava-28.2-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:958) [guava-28.2-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:749) [guava-28.2-android.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:522) [grpc-stub-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:497) [grpc-stub-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426) [grpc-core-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66) [grpc-core-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689) [grpc-core-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577) [grpc-core-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751) [grpc-core-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740) [grpc-core-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) [grpc-core-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) [grpc-core-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-api-1.27.2.jar:1.27.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."}
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:444) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:603) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.Credentials.blockingGetToCallback(Credentials.java:112) ~[google-auth-library-credentials-0.20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.auth.Credentials$1.run(Credentials.java:98) ~[google-auth-library-credentials-0.20.0.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."}
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1113) ~[google-http-client-1.34.2.jar:1.34.2]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:441) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried testing as suggested in that tutorial by using the `curl` command ([end of 6](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-integration/#5))? If so, are you sure there are messages that have been published since you created the subscription? When you ran using the gcloud command line tool, was it for the same subscription? Did you use the `--auto-ack` flag when pulling via the gcloud command line tool? When you start up your application, do you get any errors?

Comment: The `curl` command hits the endpoint. But the message is not published. Yes,  messages are being published from stackdriver. In the cmd also I use the same subscriber. I did not use the `--auto-ack` flag. I do not get any errors when starting the application. I have no idea what is wrong here. Does this work in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please see the edit above.